# How to get response from guzzle use auth and body raw?

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5.3, guzzle

I try in postman like this :

I fill just input password. Then I click button update request

The view like this :

[image]

This is header :

[image]

This is body. I select raw and input data like this :

[image]

Then I click button send and it can get the response

But when I try use guzzle 6 like this :

```
public function testApi()
{
    $requestContent = [
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        ],
        'json' => [
            'auth' => ['', 'b0a619c152031d6ec735dabd2c6a7bf3f5faaedd'],
            'ids' => ["1"]
        ]
    ];
    try {
        $client = new GuzzleHttpClient();
        $apiRequest = $client->request('POST', 'https://myshop/api/order', $requestContent);
        $response = json_decode($apiRequest->getBody());
        dd($response);
    } catch (RequestException $re) {
          // For handling exception.
    }
}
```

The result is empty

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See in Postman, you correctly specify the field `Authorization` in the "headers" tab. So it sould be the same when you use Guzzle, put it in the headers:

```
public function testApi()
{
    $requestContent = [
        'auth' => ['username', 'password']
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ],
        'json' => [
            'ids' => ["1"]
        ]
    ];

    try {
        $client = new GuzzleHttpClient;
        $apiRequest = $client->request('POST', 'https://myshop/api/order', $requestContent);
        $response = json_decode($apiRequest->getBody());
        dd($response);
    } catch (RequestException $re) {
          // For handling exception.
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems my server is in trouble. So I can not try it. Later when I try it and it works. I will accept your answer

Comment: OK, let me know. I edited my answer because I had forgotten a comma at the end of the line `'Content-Type' => 'application/json'`.

Comment: I had try it. But it does not work. It redirect to page login. It seems it is less auth. I see in your coding, there is no auth. But in the postman that I show, it's auth

Comment: Seems to be this one : `'Authorization' => 'Basic b0a619c152031d6ec735dabd2c6a7bf3f5faaedd'`. `b0a619c152031d6ec735dabd2c6a7bf3f5faaedd` and Password is inputted, it should not be the same

Comment: Password that I input: `2ae694a08465094ea04ab21506e8e740fb55b6eb`

When I click update request on the postman, the result in the header: `Basic OjJhZTY5NGEwODQ2NTA5NGVhMDRhYjIxNTA2ZThlNzQwZmI1NWI2ZWI =`

It's different

Comment: I understood what you are trying to do. When using the field "Authorization" in the headers the string following "Basic" is a token not the password. However Guzzle handles basic auth, see me edited answer?